# Multiple files comparing using python

Tags: python

I have 5 files as follows

F1:

```
ABL1
ABR
AHSG
AIRE
CCKBR
LRBA
CDC27
CENPA
```

F2:

```
AKT1
APC
APP
AR
CCND1
C11ORF2
CCNE1
CST6
CTNNB1
DBI
DEFA1
DNMT1
EEF1A1
EEF1G
```

F3:

```
ACTG1
AMPH
ANK3
APBA2
APOA1
ARHGDIA
ATP5J
DST
CA1
CA12
DDR1
CALR
CASP6
```

F4:

```
ACVR1
ARL4D
RHOA
RHOG
RHOH
BMPR1B
BMPR2
CDC20
CDK4
CDK6
CHN1
```

F5:

```
A1BG
A2M
AAMP
ACTB
ADD1
ALAS1
ALB
APLP1
ASNA1
ATP5B
```

I tried following code

```
file1=open("F1.txt","r")
file2=open("F2.txt","r")
file3=open("F3.txt","r")
file4=open("F4.txt","r")
file5=open("F5.txt","r")

list1=file1.readlines()
list2=file2.readlines()
list3=file3.readlines()
list4=file4.readlines()
list5=file5.readlines()

for line1 in list1:
    for line2 in list2:
        for line3 in list3:
            for line3 in list4:
                for line4 in list5:
                    if line1.strip() in line2.strip() in line3.strip() in line4.strip() in line5.strip():
                        print line1
                        file3.write(line1)
```

Now I want to compare all this files and find out common words using python script
Can anybody help? Can I use sets?

Comment: First [format the post](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) properly and then tell us what have you tried?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? What *did* you try so far, what failed?

Comment: `Can I use sets?` Yes you can. Sounds like a good idea. Now please try it yourself.

Comment: I'll give you a hint on using Python sets. Take a look at the `intersection()` method of [Python sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

Comment: There aren't any common words in your files (at least not common to all five of them).

Answer (score 3):

It's much easier (I didn't do any error checking when opening the files, though):

```
filenames = ["F1.txt", "F2.txt", "F3.txt", "F4.txt", "F5.txt"]
files = [open(name) for name in filenames]
sets = [set(line.strip() for line in file) 
            for file in files]
common = set.intersection(*sets)
for file in files: file.close()
```

Comment: There's a subtle danger here which has bitten me a few times.  Since the line endings/whitespace are included, if there's any difference, you'll miss a match.  Especially given the Python idiom `'\n'.join(seq)`, which doesn't add a trailing CR, it's often possible to have very rare -- and thus easy to overlook -- bugs.  I'd be defensive and either `.strip()` or `.split()`.

Comment: Is there any way to tell that I want something present at least in 3 files ?

Comment: @gthmgeeky: Sure, you could do that with [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).